# Tайлы из изображения в python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pygame, pillow, tile

Дано: карта тайлов одним изображением.
Необходимо: реализовать алгоритм вывода тайлов (спрайтов) из этого изображения по координатам.

Не знаю, понятно или нет задал вопрос. Например делаем приложение пятнашки. В котором подгружаем любую картину. Эта картинка выводится в итоге в виде перемешанных тайлов.

Можно ли реализовать алгоритм создания экземпляров тайлов стандартными модулями, чтобы на выходе был экземпляр тайла из общей картинки.
Как к примеру это можно реализовать в tkinter или pygame?

Может есть специализированные модули для этого?

У меня идея только делать экземпляры тайлов с помощью PILL, буквально нарезая изображение по координатам.

Comment: Вполне логично использовать PIL

Comment: Можно использовать и стандартные средства pygame. Сначала загружается все изображение main_image=pygame.image.load("путь/к/изображению"), затем из main_image вырезаются нужные вам изображения посредством задания координат(начало и конец участка, который вырезается) first_image=main_image.subsurface(икс_начало, игрек_начало, икс_конец,игрек_конец), second_image=main_image.subsurface(... и т.д.

Comment: Хм... Поправочка - не (икс_начало, игрек_начало, икс_конец, игрек_конец), а -  (икс_начало, игрек_начало, ширина, высота)